# How to change the values that shows a UserForm in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I have question regarding how to change what a user form shows. Basically I have a macro where a user form let the user choose the range of cells to use for the process. Then if I use the macro in other worksheet the range used before is still there. For example if in the sheet1 I selected "A20:A30" and then I use the same macro in sheet2 the range values still have selected the values of "A20:A30" of sheet 1. I know is pretty easy to just select the range I want, but the person Im helping would like the range to be blank each time you run the macro so he doesn't have to move again to the active sheet to select the range.

Here is an example with images. In the sheet "CurvasTC" (The button "Interpola" only shows the user form) I select a range and run the process clicking the button "Ejecutar". Then if I go to the sheet "Volatilidad" and run the process 
the user form appears with the references of to the sheet TC I would like that it shows blank values or at least a reference to the active sheet.

[image: Run 1]

[image: Run 2]

This is the code for the user form:

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rangoa As Range
Dim rangob As Range
Dim rangoc As Range

Set rangoa = Range(rangox.Value)
Set rangob = Range(rangoy.Value)
Set rangoc = Range(rangoxout.Value)

ventana.Hide
Run (I_Lineal(rangoa, rangob, rangoc))

End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Label3_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub rangox_BeforeDragOver(Cancel As Boolean, ByVal Data As MSForms.DataObject, ByVal x As stdole.OLE_XPOS_CONTAINER, ByVal y As stdole.OLE_YPOS_CONTAINER, ByVal DragState As MSForms.fmDragState, Effect As MSForms.fmDropEffect, ByVal Shift As Integer)

End Sub

Private Sub rangoxout_BeforeDragOver(Cancel As Boolean, ByVal Data As MSForms.DataObject, ByVal x As stdole.OLE_XPOS_CONTAINER, ByVal y As stdole.OLE_YPOS_CONTAINER, ByVal DragState As MSForms.fmDragState, Effect As MSForms.fmDropEffect, ByVal Shift As Integer)

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub
```

The code for the Interpola button is really simple is just:

```
Sub corrermacro()
   ventana.Show
End Sub
```

The user form where you select the range is called "ventana".

Comment: Please share the code for `Interpola` buttons.

Comment: @omegastripes The code for Interpola button is just ventana.show

Comment: @omegastripes the user form in the images is called "ventana"

Comment: Put code in the userform's `Activate` event to control what it displays when it is shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only hiding the form at the end of your sub. That will make it `invisible` but still there (with all its content). If you want it to be blank the next time you initialize the form then you should `unload` the form: `Unload ventana`.

So, you should add that at the end of your sub. Just know that all data on the form is after that command no longer available. Hence, this command should be the very last command in your sub:

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rangoa As Range
Dim rangob As Range
Dim rangoc As Range

Set rangoa = Range(rangox.Value)
Set rangob = Range(rangoy.Value)
Set rangoc = Range(rangoxout.Value)

ventana.Hide
Run (I_Lineal(rangoa, rangob, rangoc))
Unload ventana

End Sub
```